# Error en servidor compartido con laravel (proc_open)

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

Hola tengo la siguiente situación: estoy usando un servidor compartido para un proyecto que tengo en **laravel 6** y me esta generando el siguiente error cuando quiero hacer una búsqueda en mi tabla:

> The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your
>   PHP installation.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué versión de PHP usa tu hosting?

Comment: En el MultiPHP Manager 7.2

Comment: Revisa el valor de `disable_functions` en `phpinfo()` ó `php.ini`.

Comment: Como puedo hacer lo que me comenta en un servidor compartido de cpanel tiene alguna funcionalidad desde mi usuario que lo pueda hacer desde la consola del cpanel

Answer (score 0):

Ya ha pasado un tiempo, debe estar resuelto, pero tenía el mismo problema y sólo lo pude solucionar quitando proc_open y otros varios proc_* de disable_functions en php.ini, si es un servidor compartido y no te dejan modificar php.ini estás complicado, te diría que intentes resolver la búsqueda de una manera diferente, o sea, utilizar diferentes funciones, prueba y error para evitar el problema con proc_open.

Otro comentario, en algún momento vas a necesitar actualizar versión de Laravel y ahí ya no hay forma de evitar el problema con proc_open (no recuerdo si me bloqueaba la actualización a Laravel 7 u 8), si es un proyecto que hay que mantener a largo plazo debes tener en cuenta que estará ese problema. Saludos.